# AFNetworking POST Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Here's my question:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"type": @"5", @"xq": @"a", @"apid": @"b", @"apsecret": @"c", @"astoken": @"d"};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

if i use GET :

```
[manager GET:@"http://127.0.0.1/123.php" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {   
NSLog(@"responseObject : %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
 }];
```

i can get $_GET['parameters'] value

but when i use POST :

```
[manager POST:@"http://127.0.0.1/123.php" parameters:parameters 
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
{ 
   NSLog(@"responseObject : %@", responseObject); 
}     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
{ 
   NSLog(@"error : %@", error); 
}];
```

i always get $_POST['parameters'] value is null.....

am i doing something wrong in the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for all,

i found it's can work

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/123.php"]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"123.php"
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"responseObject : %@", responseObject);
      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 4th line of 1st code snippet to,

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
```

Comment: Xcode says : No visible @interface for 'AFHTTPRequestSerializer<AFURLRequestSerialization>' declares the selector 'setValue:'

Comment: then how did you managed to setValue with your original code without an error?